# Laravel 4 : Route to localhost/controller/action

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, url-routing, laravel-routing

I'm more or less new to Laravel 4. I've never used routes before but normally what I'm used to is url/controller/action and then the backend routing for me. I've read the documentation for routes and controllers a few times as well as read through some tutorials and so, I'm trying to figure out how to get this to work without writing a route for every controller and action.

I tried something like

```
Route::get('{controller}/{action}', function($controller, $action = 'index'){
    return $controller."@".$action;
});
```

Now then, I know this is wrong since it doesn't work, but what am I missing? On most tutorials and stuff I'm seeing an route for more or less every controller and action like:

```
Route::get('/controller/action' , 'ControllerName@Action');
```

Which seems silly and like a waste of time to me.

Is there anyway to achieve what I want?

Comment: It is not silly and a waste of time. Route definition provides alot of functionality and features as your application grows. Read this blog for more info: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking for a more automated routing, this would be the Laravel 4 way:

Route:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
```

Controller (in this case UsersController.php):

```
public function getIndex()
{
    // routed from GET request to /users
}

public function getProfile()
{
    // routed from GET request to /users/profile
}

public function postProfile()
{
    // routed from POST request to /users/profile
}

public function getPosts($id)
{
    // routed from GET request to: /users/posts/42
}
```

As The Shift Exchange mentioned, there are some benefits to doing it the verbose way. In addition to the excellent article he linked, you can create a [name for each route](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes), for example:

```
Route::get("users", array(
    "as"=>"dashboard",
    "uses"=>"UsersController@getIndex"
));
```

Then when creating urls in your application, use a helper to generate a [link to a named route](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#basic-routing):

```
$url = URL::route('dashboard');
```

Links are then future proofed from changes to controllers/actions.

You can also generate links directly to actions which would still work with automatic routing.

```
$url = URL::action('UsersController@getIndex');
```

Comment: And if the function has multiple words like, getOldProfile().
this will be a GET request to users/old-profile

Answer (score 7):

```
app\
    controllers\
        Admin\
           AdminController.php
        IndexController.php
```

```
Route::get('/admin/{controller?}/{action?}', function($controller='Index', $action='index'){
        $controller = ucfirst($controller);
        $action = $action . 'Action';
        return App::make("Admin\\{$controller}Controller")->$action();
    });

Route::get('/{controller?}/{action?}', function($controller='Index', $action='index'){
        $controller = ucfirst($controller);
        $action = $action . 'Action';
        return App::make("{$controller}Controller")->$action();
    });
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation as to why this answer helps.

Comment: This is universal method to route controller/action for all controllers automatically. Plus it allow keep controllers in separate folders.

Comment: You really should add some explanation to this post, rather than just pure code.

Comment: You really should not add some explanation to this post, it's clear! ◕‿◕

Answer (score 0):

I come from .Net world and routing is typically done:

```
/{Controller}/{action}/{id}
```

Which looks like:

```
/Products/Show/1 OR /Products/Show/Beverages
```

In Laravel I accomplish this routing like so:

```
Route::get('/{controller?}/{action?}/{id?}', function ($controller='Home', $action='index', $id = null) {
    $controller = ucfirst($controller);
    return APP::make("{$controller}Controller")->$action($id);
});
```

The controller would look roughly like so:

```
class ProductsController extends BaseController {
    public function Show($id) {
        $products = array( 1 => array("Price" => "$600","Item" => "iPhone 6"),
                           2 => array("Price" => "$700", "Item" => "iPhone 6 Plus") );

        if ($id == null) {
            echo $products[1]["Item"];
        } else {
            echo $products[$id]["Item"];
        }

    }
}
```