# Get controller action from url, laravel

Tags: php, laravel, filter, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Can I get the controller action from given URL?

In my project, I will have different layout used for admin and normal users. i.e.

> something.com/content/list - will show layout 1.
>
> something.com/admin/content/list - will show layout 2.
>
> (But these need to be generated by the same controller)

I have added filter to detect the pattern `'admin/*'` for this purpose. Now I need to call the action required by the rest of the URL ('`content/list`' or anything that will appear there). Meaning, there could be anything after `admin/` it could be `foo/1/edit` (in which case foo controller should be called) or it could be `bar/1/edit` (in which case bar controller should be called). That is why the controller name should be generated dynamically from the url that the filter captures,

So, I want to get the controller action from the URL (content/list) and then call that controller action from inside the filter.

Can this be done?

Comment: How did you created routes for these ? Can you post the routes related to these ?

Comment: Can you show the routes for these ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who participated.

I just found the solution to my problem in another thread. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178023/laravel-4-route-to-localhost-controller-action)

This is what I did.

```
if(Request::is('admin/*')) {
    $my_route = str_replace(URL::to('admin'),"",Request::url());

    $request = Request::create($my_route);
    return Route::dispatch($request)->getContent();
}
```

I could not find these methods in the documentation. So I hope, this will help others too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Request::segment(index)` to get part/segment of the `url`

```
// http://www.somedomain.com/somecontroller/someaction/param1/param2
$controller = Request::segment(1); // somecontroller
$action = Request::segment(2); // someaction
$param1 = Request::segment(3); // param1
$param2 = Request::segment(3); // param2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RESTful Controller](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers)

```
Route:controller('/', 'Namespace\yourController');
```

But the method have to be prefixed by HTTP verb and I am not sure whether it can contain more url segment, in your case, I suggest just use:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
{
    //map certain path to certain controller, and just throw 404 if no matching route  
    //it's good practice
    Route::('content/list', 'yourController@yourMethod');

});
```

Comment: This would be one way of achieving what I want. But that is not the point. I was wondering if the name of a specific controller action can be obtained from dynamic URLs and then call that controller no matter what we get in URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your controller function -

```
if (Request::is('admin/*'))
{
    //layout for admin (layout 2)
}else{
    //normal layout (layout 1)
}
```

Comment: I have done this already. Now, I need to look at what is found after "admin/" and then call the controller corresponding to that url. Look at the edit i have posted in question.

Comment: read the individual uri segment using `$segment = Request::segment(1);` and then redirect accordingly. Like change the parameter value like 1,2 .. depending upon the parameter you need to use to decide for redirection.

Comment: Redirect would not work for me, because that would change the current URL from  'admin/foo/1/edit' to 'foo/1/edit'. I would need the 'admin' part in the URL to determine if its a normal user or admin user.

Comment: What I want is to be able to get the controller action name of the rest of the URL and then call that controller.

Comment: This is not redirect, read the uri segment using this method and then use that segment value to decide which layout you need to load.

Comment: check this - [automated routing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178023/laravel-4-route-to-localhost-controller-action)

Comment: I just found the exact solution that i was looking for. I have posted an answer myself. Please take a look. It might prove useful to everyone. And thanks of participating. :)