# laravel 4: difference between resource and controller in Route class

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

what is the difference between static Route methods "resource" and "controller"

```
Route::controller()
```

and

```
Route::resource()
```

thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 - Route::resource vs Route::controller. Which to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102534/laravel-4-routeresource-vs-routecontroller-which-to-use)

Comment: I think there are some difference here, when request /url/create , Route::resource request create() method, but Route::controller request getCreate() method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got something:

```
Route::resource()
```

- force you to use default methods (index, create, store, show, edit, update, destroy) with no way to add new methods in controller class (no way to call the new method)

but

```
Route::controller()
```

- let you to define unlimited methods inside controller class
- need to define used HTTP verb before function name like (postCreate, anyCreate)

Answer (score 1):

You can read about this in the official documentation:

http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

```
 Route::controller()
```

It will declare all routes you define as functions starting for html verbs, example from the documentation:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');

  class UserController extends BaseController {

  public function getIndex()
  {
    //
  }

  public function postProfile()
  {
    //
  }

  public function anyLogin()
  {
    //
  }

}
```

In other hand:

http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

```
Route::resource()
```

Is basically used when you use the create controller command of artisan:

```
php artisan controller:make PhotoController
```

It will generate all the routes generated by the artisan command, basically crud routes.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the routing that occurs when you do both:

```
Route::controller('test', 'TestController');
Route::resource('othertest', 'OtherTestController');
```

Here's a picture of what I'm about to write out in text for you, if it's any easier:
[image: "php artisan routes" result of the above routes]

The following is an all-in-one. For example, if you `GET` to `laravel_dir/test/page`, it will look for method `getPage()` in `TestController`. If you `POST` to `laravel_dir/test/page`, it will look for `postPage()`

> **URI**: GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE test/{_missing}
>
> **Route Name**: None
>
> **Action**: TestController@missingMethod

Below is what results from the resource route... You'll see that it is very useful for CRUD in one line for your routes.php file.

> **URI**: GET|HEAD othertest
>
> **Route Name**: othertest.index
>
> **Action**: OtherTestController@index
>
> ---
>
> **URI**: GET|HEAD othertest/create
>
> **Route Name**: othertest.create
>
> **Action**: OtherTestController@create
>
> ---
>
> **URI**: POST othertest
>
> **Route Name**: othertest.store
>
> **Action**: OtherTestController@store
>
> ---
>
> **URI**: GET|HEAD othertest/{othertest}
>
> **Route Name**: othertest.show
>
> **Action**: OtherTestController@show
>
> ---
>
> **URI**: GET|HEAD othertest/{othertest}/edit
>
> **Route Name**: othertest.edit
>
> **Action**: OtherTestController@edit
>
> ---
>
> **URI**: PUT othertest/{othertest}
>
> **Route Name**: othertest.update
>
> **Action**: OtherTestController@update
>
> ---
>
> **URI**: PATCH othertest/{othertest}
>
> **Route Name**: othertest.update (shares the name with the above)
>
> **Action**: OtherTestController@update
>
> ---
>
> **URI**: DELETE othertest/{othertest}
>
> **Route Name**: othertest.destroy
>
> **Action**: OtherTestController@destroy

Answer (score 0):

This method auto detect "GET", "POST", "PUT/PATCH", "DELETE" methods.

```
Route::resource()
```

This method auto detect argument from URL

```
Route::controller()
```

Also look it: [Laravel 4 : Route to localhost/controller/action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178023/laravel-4-route-to-localhost-controller-action)

Comment: I think both interact in same way (with HTTP verbs)