# How to create a default route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I just started with PHP Laravel and i couldn't figure out how to create a default route.

With ASP.NET MVC you could create a default route that would point to the requested controller and action. So you don't have to create a new route for each controller & action.

Is this possible?

Something like:

```
Route::get('{controller}/{index}', 'HomeController@index');
```

The HomeController would be the default is no controller was specified and index would be the default action if no action was specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can create resource controllers in Laravel but the exact "default" functionality you are looking for doesn't exist out of the box. Check out the resource controllers:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

However, this is only really for RESTful routes.

If you want to create it manually then you want to do something like this:

```
Route::get('{controller}/{action}', function($controller, $action) {
    $controller = ucwords($controller).'Controller';
    App::make($controller)->{$action}();
});
```

Comment: Is this a recommended method of routing? Or at least not "not recommended"?

Comment: I would not recommend this. It's better to define the routes you need explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Route::controller`

Take a look at this answer, it may be close to what you want

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18180606/4433967